# Delphi - Get all column names of selected row from DBGrid

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I'm using the following code to display the values of every column from a row I select in my `DBGrid`, to a `Memo`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  with DBGrid1 do
  begin
    for i:=0 to FieldCount-1 do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Fields[i].AsString);
  end;
end;
```

Anyone have any ideas how to also get the **column names**, before the **value**?

For example 1st column is named `ID`, the 1st `value` shown on the `memo` is the `ID` value (let's say 15) - I'd like it to be ID:15 (column_name:column_value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need column name and values

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  with DBGrid1 do
  begin
    for i:=0 to Columns.Count-1 do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Columns[i].FieldName+':'+ Columns[i].Field.AsString);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe "displaylabel" is also interessting for you

Comment: @ChristineRoss Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look in to that too :)